# Bash sh know the language in use

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line, sh

How can I know what language and in use?

I tried to use the following command on the mac but it doesn't return anything.

```
echo (locale | grep LANGUAGE | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1)
```

Comment: grep LANG   ?? that works for me

Comment: Even `echo $LANG`

Comment: Missing the `$` in command substitution syntax. `$(locale | ...)` would work. (The `echo` and the command substitution are pointless in this context, but fix the syntax and they'd work, just with the associated inefficiency).

Comment: @Pete: Just `echo grep LANG`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I tried but it doesn't print anything: `echo $(locale | grep LANGUAGE | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1)`

Comment: @ArslanSohailBano: I tried this way, do you think this is correct?
It seems to work, what is the result if you try it?
`echo $LANG | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1`

Comment: This is the output I get: `$ echo $LANG | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1` : `en`

Comment: What `locale` returns to you?

Comment: `echo $LANG | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1`  Is there a way to have the same information also on windows systems? –

Comment: @Paul, if you grep for `LANGUAGE` but the output contains `LANG`, well, there's your problem -- you need to grep for something that actually exists; that's a thinko/typo, not a shell syntax question.

Answer (score 0):

```
locale | grep LANG | cut -d\" -f2 | cut -d. -f1
```

Returns en_GB for me. Would that do?

Comment: I tried on mac, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Paul works well on my mac...

Comment: I used to put `echo` first thinking it should be used for printing.

What is the difference between:
`echo $LANG | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1` e
`local | grep LANG | cut -d\" -f2 | cut -d_ -f1`.

Which would be better to use?

Comment: Is there a way to have the same information also on windows systems?

Comment: @Paul, the reason to use `locale` is that it figures out what's configured even when there _isn't_ an explicit `LANG` variable.

Comment: @Paul, btw, `echo` prints things, but `locale` _also_ prints its output; so do `grep` and `cut`. You don't need to capture output (that was going to be printed anyhow) and then print it again; that's just extra inefficiency for no reason.

Comment: On that note, perhaps see [Useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html%C2%A0#echo)